# syntax error on createCell

Tags: java, apache-poi

i'm getting a syntax error on row.createCell line

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "createCell", = expected after 
     this token
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

this is the code

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)2);
row.createCell(0).setCellValue(1.1);
```

Comment: What library is this? The signature of the createCell method would be helpful.

Comment: How is createCell declared in HSSFRow?

Comment: The syntax error is certainly not in the code you provided.

Comment: was just following Apache POI HSSF implementation shown http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0516.html

Comment: We may need more detail. Can you post a short but complete program which demostrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are these statements?  If they're in the field declaration section of a class, then the last statement can't appear there.